# Does such a conformal mapping onto the unit disk exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

With a classic Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, we can map a square area in the complex plane to the unit disk (image below, left). I am wondering if there exists a mapping in the unit disk which can effecticely collapse the 3 o'clock and 9 o'clock quadrants of the unit circle (orange dashed line, left) to a single point to yield a field similar to what I have approximate sketched on the right.

I believe some complications could arise from the fact that the mapping is no longer 1-to-1 on the unit circle (as we collapse some stretches of the boundary to a point). If this is a precluding issue, I would alternatively be interested in a solution which reduces these edgepoints of the orange quadrants to a very small distance. Furthermore, if there were a method to obtain the right side field directly, this would also be sufficient.

Does such a mapping or field exist? If so, how would I go about constructing it?
[image]

Comment: what properties exactly you want for $f$ - note that if $f$ is locally conformal ($f'(z) \ne 0, |z| <1$) and its image is the interior of a Jordan curve, $f$ is automatically a biholomorphic map that extends to a continuous injective map on the boundary, so any (holomorphic) $f$ as above would need to have singular points inside the disc

Comment: I'm afraid I am not deep enough into the theory yet to give a very well formulated response, but I'll try: I don't require a biholomorphic map (which is, if I understand correctly, one with an inverse map - this seems impossible, I think, at least for the points which collapse). I also do not really have a preference of where the collapsed points lie - if there would lie directly on 3 o'clock and 9 o'clock (so the resulting field is axial symmetric both in the horizontal and vertical plane), as long as the result is symmetric with respect to the vertical axis.

Comment: My point is that if you want a holomorphic $f$ like that, it must have singularities inside the disc (points where $f'=0$) since the shape of the image dictates it

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, is there a way to learn where those singularities would be?

Comment: Actually thinking more, no such map can exist since it can be analytically continued across the arc where is constant by the reflection principle and then it is constant by the identity theorem

Comment: I have since searched some more, and I think this (https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/pure/staff/kisilv/courses/color-figures/epal1-ws-fig094.png) might be similar to what I require (full page here: https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/pure/staff/kisilv/courses/color-figures/epal1-ws-fig.html). Seems to obtained by an 'elliptic form of a Cayley transformation' if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by a "mapping" you mean "a nonconstant holomorphic  mapping." Then such a mapping cannot exist: If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the open disk $D$ such that $f$ has constant radial limit on a nontrivial arc on $\partial D$ then $f$ is constant. This is a special case of [Riesz uniqueness theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riesz_theorem#:%7E:text=Riesz%27s%20uniqueness%20theorem%20for%20bounded,proved%20by%20the%20brothers%20F.). More generally (but this requires more work), if $D$ is any domain in ${\mathbb C}$ bounded by a Jordal curve, $A\subset \partial D$ is a nontrivial arc and $f: D\to {\mathbb C}$ is holomorphic with constant limit on $A$, then $f$ is constant.

Of course, if by a mapping you mean merely a smooth (even injective) mapping of an open round disk, then collapsing a boundary arc of a round disk is clearly possible.